# Publishing a python package to a repository subfolder on jfrog artifactory using poetry

Tags: python, artifactory, setup.py, python-poetry

I'm trying to move my project from pip+requirements.txt to poetry and publish it to private Artifactory. However, I want my packages to be published in a specific subfolder.
For example, if my package is called "foo", I want to publish it in the folder "bar", which is similar to the current situation (all the packages are deployed inside "bar" and I want to keep it this way).

[image: Current situation]

Until now I succeeded in creating this effect using setup.py in the following way:

```
setup(
    name='bar/foo',
    version='0.0.1',
...
)
```

I understand that according to PEP the package name 'bar/foo' is illegal, however Artifactory dealt with it for some reason until now.

How can I make Poetry or Jfrog obey this structure? Can I create a custom layout for this repository in Jfrog and if so, how do I do it?

P.S: To set up the repository in poetry I'm running:

```
poetry config repositories.myrepo https://myrepo.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/pypi/private-python/
```

And my pyproject.toml file has the following:

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "myrepo"
url = "https://myrepo.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/pypi/private-python/simple"
default = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is currently supported in poetry.